# Subtract values by columns, value roll over

Tags: r

Let's say I have this dataframe,

```
data<- data.frame (A = c (6,5,4,3,2,1), B=c(0,0,4,4,0,0))
```

And I want to subtract B from A, to create this, C=A-B

```
data2 <- data.frame(A = c (6,5,4,3,2,1), B=c(0,0,4,4,0,0), C=c(6,5,0,0,0,0))
```

From row 4, A is less than B, however I don't want the negative value, and I want to keep C>=0, and the excess value will be rolled over to the next row and do the deduction. Any idea which function I should apply?

Comment: Can you show what you want C to be? I am not resolving "excess value will be rolled over to the next row and do the deduction."

Comment: Hi, basically i would like C = A-B. but when A is less than B, I would like C=0, and the excess value will be carried over to the next row.

Comment: By next row, are you referring to a not-presented D? Do you see my confusion? By presenting the solution that you seek, we can help you identify the needed code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a very clean solution but your problem seems to imply an iterative search :

```
while(sum(data$B)>0)
  data <- data.frame(A=ifelse(data$A>=data$B,data$A-data$B,0),
                     B=lag(ifelse(data$A>=data$B,0,data$B-data$A),default=0))
```